# should i create swap space in my laptop?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, memory, performance, swap-file

My Laptop has i7 10th gen + 8GB ram
NVIDIA GeForce MX230 2Gb graphic card

my daily usage inteliiJ (3-4 instance), chrome (15-20 tabs), postman (1 instance), VS code(2 instance),

Comment: Well, you described the software, while you needed to describe the memory pressure. What is `cat /proc/meminfo` under typical load? You calo can create *some* swap file, observer how much of it is actually in use, and then re-create it with reasonable headroom.

Comment: Since you tagged "Ubuntu" then you should know Ubuntu uses a swapfile by default. No need to create a classic swap partition. If the upper limit - 2GB, I think - isn't enough you can easily increase it.

Comment: yes but don't use normal swap and use zram instead: [How do I use swap space for emergencies only?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/499645/44425)

Answer (score 0):

YES.  You should almost always have swap on a Linux system.  It is OK for swap to be a file on the disk, but it should exist (even if its only 500 megs).   You can set vm.swappiness=0 to try and avoid swapping, but **the OS needs swap for memory management.**

Also, if you want to be able to Hibernate the system, swap must be >= RAM.

Comment: Ubuntu automatically creates the swapfile during installation. For the vast majority of users there's no need to change any of the parameters. The question suggests the OP is thinking about a swap partition which isn't necessary for Ubuntu since many releases ago.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Our reading of the question is different, and while the default swappiness works OK, its not a 1 size fits all, and especially as the OP likely has reasons they don't want the system swapping.

Comment: Indeed our reading is different. I think you're reading too much :-)